# Net Core 2 app login redirect not working in azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azureportal

Ive inherited a asp net core 2 mvc app that we want to host in azure. I have managed to publish it to azure but when i access the url i get this error:

> AADSTS50011: The reply address
>   'http://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc' does not match the
>   reply addresses configured for the application:
>   'xxxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'.

The appsettings.json has it configured as:

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
```

The url of the site is
http://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net

When i run it in my local development environment the login redirect works perfectly. I guess something needs to be configured in the Azure portal but where do i find it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the application in Azure AD, and add `https://myAzureSite.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc` in the Reply URLs.

Go to Azure Active Directory -> App registrations -> All apps -> Find your app -> Settings -> Reply URLs.

If you don't see Azure Active Directory on the left sidebar, you can find it from All services.

Note you should use HTTPS, not HTTP.
It is possible the reply URL is already configured, but your login would fail since you are accessing your app over HTTP.